# git pull origin master is still ahead of origin/master by 1 commit

Tags: git

I made a commit on my local copy of `master` and ultimately added this commit to a separate branch / pull request. Now that I'm back on my local master, I start here:

```
git:(master) git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I want to back out of this commit, since it will merge from another branch, so I:

```
git: (master) git pull origin master
From https://github.com/basho-labs/the-riak-community
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

And I'm still in the same state. To back out of this, I:

```
git:(master) git checkout HEAD~1
Note: checking out 'HEAD~1'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at abd0327...
```

But what's the cleanest way to handle the history? I don't want yet another `commit`, so I'm not sure how to proceed. I've reviewed the past conversations with similar names and don't see a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally pushed more commits and had to think through this a little more. I ended up:

```
git:(master)git reset --hard abd0327ec1b
HEAD is now at abd0327 Shortened introduction
git:(master)
git:(master) git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
git:(master)
git:(master) git push -f
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/basho-labs/the-riak-community.git
 + 5e39499...abd0327 master -> master (forced update)
```

And I'm happy with the history:

[image: omglog output]